# AngularJS: Upload picture to facebook graph api as multipart/formdata

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload a photo to facebook using the method shown in 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/

I can get the upload to work if the photo that is already on the internet by using the url parameter as shown below.

```
$scope.uploadPicture = function () {        
    FB.api(
        "/me/photos", 'post', {
            caption: "Testing uploadPicture",
            access_token: authFact.getAccessToken(),
            url: 'http://www.website.com/somejpg.jpg'
        },
        function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response);
                } 
            }
        );
    };
```

I want to be able to post a picture from my local machine as a multipart/form-data.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

My html looks like this

```
<form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fileInput">File input</label>
                <input type="file" id="fileInput">
                <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="itemName">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemName" placeholder="Enter Name here..">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using source instead of url, url is for files already on the internet.

```
<input type="file" id="souce">
```